# How can I hook the window change size or position event in python?

Tags: python, win32gui

I hope to hook the window size change , then I can do something like get window tilte text .

So , I use

> SetWinEventHook

and parameter

> EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND

to find foreground window ,
but I don't know how to hook if the window change size or position.
I think I should use

> WH_CBT or WH_CALLWNDPROC

to hook the window if change size.
Is that right ?
Can give me some infomation or example to research .

Thanks.

Comment: pywinauto 0.6.0 currently can hook low level mouse and keyboard events. See example: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/blob/master/examples/hook_and_listen.py We want to implement more hooks, but have no much time for that. Also it's possible to use AutomationEventHandlers from MS UI Automation, another big topic in TODO list.